# Rapidclipse - changing theme at runtime

Tags: rapidclipse

Is there a possibility to change the Theme at runtime in rapidclipse? I do have user who like the dark theme where other users prefere the light theme.

As of now I just have the @Theme annotation which is setting one theme.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find anything in the Vaadin Documentation regarding dynamic setting of the Theme-Variant.

But looking around I found this tutorial https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/toggle-dark-theme#_option_2_change_between_light_and_dark_theme_on_the_fly

By adding and removing **Lumo.DARK** from **UI.getCurrent().getElement().getThemeList()** I was able to switch between light and dark.

Downsides to this as the comments from that tutorial suggest, this seems to be more of a workaround than an actual solution. If the body tag overflows then you will see a white page where it overflows.

I hope this still helps.

Comment: I would not call this a workaround. You can also define the theme variant in parts of the UI by setting it in specific component, or layout.

Comment: This might work in Vaadin 14 / rapdicclipse X - However I am still on Rapidclipse 4 / Vaadin 7 - where this is not applicable

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for Vaadin 7.7.13:

```
    this.getUI().setTheme("MyTheme");
```

I have packed the code into an clicklistener of a button. "MyTheme" has to be present under *WebContent/Vaadin/themes*